# Unable to access System storage error (ps4)

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

Recently, I got my hands onto a ps4. The problem is, when I started it said "Cannot start the ps4. Please insert a USB drive with the 5.55 or higher reinstall files."
I did that and put it in. After it initialized, it got 20% of the way before stating "Cannot access the system storage. E-(something, will edit with code)"
I was ticked now. The heck?
All the tutorials on the web relate to a different error, thus I don't think they can help.
Can someone explain what's going on, and a way to FIX it?

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with the HDD. If you have an old HDD lying around, (or an old SSD), I'd replace the PS4 HDD with it and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Getting "Cannot access the system storage" while initializing the PS4 System Software usually means that the hard drive sectors are no longer readable.

As Nolonar points out in the comments, you should try to get a new 2.5' SATA drive that can be either an HDD or SDD and see if the system software can be installed that way.